# Nested loops complexity

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity

I've this C# method:

```
private void Process()
{

  foreach (Vat vat in vats) // n elements
  {
    foreach (ProcessResultRow row in processResultRows) // m elements
    {
      // something here
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Shop> entry in _shopsList) // j elements
    {
      // something else here
    }
  }

}
```

I know two nested loops have a `O(n^2)` complexity. Is it right in this example?

I am undecided because of the fact that within the external cycle I have two for cicles at the same level.

Comment: its off-topic but basically you are correct nested loop are o(n^2), in you case you have o(n* (n+n)) = o(2n^2) =o(n^2) this is because the 3rd loop is not nestead and it's "linear with the 2nd loop, in fact, you can have how many non-nested for loop and you still have o(n^2), **Edit** if the length of the for loops are different you will have o(n+m+....)^2

Comment: Neither of the inner loops reference the outer loop variable, though? So surely the big-O notation doesn't just have `n` (the number of elements in the outer loop), but it also has `m` (the number of elements in the unrelated inner loop)

Comment: How about `O(n * (m + j))` ?

Comment: @canton7 the three cicles have respectively n, m, j number of elements. They are not related.

Comment: No. n^2 is if you had N rows of data that you were sorting and comparing the first row with every row then the second row with every row and then the third row with every row.  In your case the two inner foreach loops are not N in length (or I can't tell from code).  You have vats which in this case is N.

Comment: The answer is obviously no, but is the question what the time complexity of that method ?

Comment: basically @RobinBennett have the right answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prividing that loops don't have `return`, `break` and alike (e.g. throwing exception) the compleixity is

```
O(n * (m + j)) == O(n * m) + O(n * j)
```

if both `m` and `j` are *constants* we have

```
O(n*m + n*j) == m * O(n) + j * O(n) == O(n)
```

if at least one `m` or `j` such that `m ~ n` or `j ~ n` then we have

```
// here m ~ n and j is some const
O(n * m) + O(n * j) == O(n * n) + j * O(n) == O(n**2) + O(n) == O(n**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @RobinBennet said, the answer is `O(n * (m + j))`.

The outer loop iterates n times (one for each element).
For each element within the outer loops, the first inner loop iterates m times and the second j times - so for each element you perform O(m + j) steps. Iterate over n elements, O(n * (m + j).

That is, assuming that m, j are not related to n - if, for example m = j = n, you'd get O(n^2)